# Javafx Menu - Text under icon

Tags: css, javafx, menu, menubar

In my JavaFX project, I am trying to add an icon on **Menu**(mnAdmin) in the **MenuBar** using the CSS code below

```
#mnAdmin > .label {
          -fx-graphic: url("../images/Admin-icon32.png");
    }
```

and am getting the icon beside the text and I would like to get the text at the bottom of the icon.

[image: What I am getting now]
[image: What would like to get]

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: try to also set the label's contentDisplay property via css

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you very much `-fx-content-display:top;` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by kleopatra modified the code as stated below and it works well.

```
 #mnAdmin > .label {
              -fx-graphic: url("../images/Admin-icon32.png");
              -fx-content-display:top;
        }
```